# Basic C++ exercise (command prompt doesn't show any cout. No compiler error)

Tags: c++

Just approaching C++ programming.
The exercise I have to do: "In a store there are 500 products that are identified by ID, product name, brand, shelf (0 to 34). Using local variables implement two functions to: 
- load datas;
- find the shelf where most of the products are."
Here's what I did. 
(I used 10 instead of 500).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class product {
public: 
    string ID, prod_name, brand;
    float price; 
    int shelf;
    void data_load(); 
    int freq_shelf();
};

product a[10];        

void data_load() {
    int i;
    cout << "Recording ten products" << endl;
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << "Id product "<<i<<":" << endl;
        cin >> a[i].ID;
        cout << "Name product "<<i<<":" << endl;
        cin >> a[i].prod_name;
        cout << "Brand product "<<i<<":" << endl;
        cin >> a[i].brand;
        cout << "Price product "<<i<<":" << endl;
        cin >> a[i].price;
        cout << "Shelf (shelves 0-34)"<<i<<":" << endl;
        cin >> a[i].shelf;
        if (a[i].shelf<0 || a[i].shelf>34) {
            cout << "I said 0 a 34" << endl;
         }
    }
}

int freq_shelf() {
int coor[2];     //first element should be the number of the shelf, second one how many times that shelf is found
int i, j, k, c;
int t[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};     //kth-element indicates the number of presences of the ith-element      
for (k=0; k<10; k++) {
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (j=0; i<10; j++) {
            if (a[i].shelf==a[j].shelf) {
                t[k]++; 
                }
           }
     }
}

int max=t[0];
for (c=1; c<10; c++) 
{
    if (t[c]>max) 
    {
        max=t[c];      //c should be the number of the shelf, max how many times that shelf is found
        coor[2]=coor[c, max];
        cout << "The most frequent shelf is "<<coor[1]<<". It is found "<<coor[2]<<" times." << endl;
return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
void data_load();
int freq_shelf();
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 I get no error when debugging and compiling, but the command prompt goes straight to 'Press any key to continue'.
Anyone can explain why?
Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: `void data_load();` definitely doesn't what you want/think, and neither does `int freq_shelf();`.  You want to **call** these functions...

Comment: Remove the return types of the functions when calling them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declared a function instead of calling it;

Change

```
int main() 
{
void data_load();
```

To

```
int main() 
{
    data_load();
```

Comment: Right. Works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Other than the replies provided. The

```
system("PAUSE")
```

would need the

```
<stdlib.h>
```

header for system functions.

Other than that in visual studio generally,

```
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
  _getch(); // or getch();
  return 0;
}
```

to make the output stay on the screen.

Also, the answer by Bartek is correct and adding to it

```
int freq_shelf();
```

change it to,

```
freq_shelf();
```

you can see the details of functions in this simple example

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

and not to recommend an external website, let me give you an example.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void Test()
{
  cout << "Function runs nicely";
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{

    int x;

    x = add(2, 3);

    cout << "Integer Function Result\t" << x <<endl;

    Test();
    return 0;
}
```

you can see the function calls in the main do not need type declarations.

These are the basic things I noticed, Cheers ! :)

Comment: I highly disrecommend linking to `cplusplus.com` as a reliable source on C++ functions. It requires a proper book to learn them properly, and "simple tutorial" will most likely just misguide people.

Comment: Apologies, did not mean to suggest the website just the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
data_load();
freq_shelf();`
```

in `main` rather than

```
void data_load();
int freq_shelf();
```

Because you want to **call** those functions. Don't add the return type when calling functions.

Comment: @CoolGuy no, he doesn't have to accept an answer; it's completely up to the asker to do that.

Comment: @CoolGuy: It's not required, though it _is_ encouraged.